# Google BigQuery undocumented error 403

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

> googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/674064471933/datasets/vibetraceLIVE/tables/51c01e03ed14d94e30000003_events/insertAll?alt=json
>   returned "Exceeded rate limits: too many inserted rows per table for
>   this table">

```
403: Exceeded rate limits: too many inserted rows per table for this table
```

I haven't found this error anywhere on the web.
What limit am i crossing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://developers.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery, specifically:

> Maximum rows per second: 10,000 rows per second, per table.
>
> Exceeding
> this amount will cause quota_exceeded errors. For additional support
> up to 100,000 rows per second, per table, please contact a sales
> representative.

Are you trying to insert more than 10,000 rps? To approve a higher quota, contact https://cloud.google.com/contact/.

Comment: I was thinking about this, but the error code didn't sound like it. I made a 10k request every second and it seems i have crossed that line, inadvertently. Thanks!